# How to set up Google+ authorship in Drupal 7

Tags: google-search-console

How do you set up Google+ authorship in Drupal 7?

So I can link my drupal website to our Google+ account so that our Google+ profile pic can appear in the search engines next to our site.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is with the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module:

> The Metatag module allows you to automatically provide structured
>   metadata, aka "meta tags", about your website. In the context of
>   search engine optimization, when people refer to meta tags they are
>   usually referring to the meta description tag and the meta keywords
>   tag that may help improve the rankings and display of your site in
>   search engine results.

After you install/enable the module, you can edit the metatags at admin/config/search/metatags  The Google+ Author is under Advanced.